# Extend identity map on $\mathbb{Q}$ to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow{\mathbb{Q}} $ be the identity map on the subspace topology of the euclidean topology. Is it possible to extend $f$ to $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow{\mathbb{Q}}$ where $F$ is continuous and $F(x) = f(x)$ for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the usual topologies, because $\mathbb R$ is connected and $\mathbb Q$ is totally disconnected. The image $f(\mathbb R)$ of any continuous map $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ must then be a single point (the continuous image of a connected space is connected).

Comment: This is what I was thinking then got confused on the concept of connectedness. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $A$ is a dense subset of the  topological space $B$, and $f: A \to C$ is continuous where $C$ is a Hausdorff space, then a continuous extension $g: B \to C$ is unique if it exists.  In your case the obvious extension is the identity $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, whose range is of course not in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: How would you determine that the obvious extension is $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$?